# unable to itherate through the array perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have this perl script:

```
my %perMpPerMercHash;

foreach my $sheet () {   #proper ranges specified
    foreach my $row ( ) {    #proper ranges specified
        #required variables declared.
        push(@{$perMpPerMercHash{join("-", $mercId, $mpId)}}, $mSku); 
    }
}

#Finally 'perMpPerMercHash' will be a hash of array`
foreach my $perMpPerMerc ( keys %perMpPerMercHash ) {
    &genFile($perMpPerMerc, $perMpPerMercHash{$perMpPerMerc});
}

sub genFile {
    my ( $outFileName, @skuArr ) = @_;
    my $output = new IO::File(">$outFileName");
    my $writer = new XML::Writer( OUTPUT => $output, DATA_MODE => 1, DATA_INDENT => 2);
 #mpId is generated.
    &prepareMessage($writer, $mpId, @skuArr);
}

sub prepareMessage {
    my ( $writer,  $mpId, @skuArr ) = @_;
    my $count = 1;
    print Dumper \@skuArr;    #Printing correctly, 8-10 values.
    foreach my $sku ( @skuArr ) {   #not iterating.
        print "loop run" , $sku, "\n";   #printed only once.
    }
}
```

Can somebody please help why this is happening. I am new to perl and could not understand this anomaly.

EDIT:
output of Dumper:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'A',
          'B',
          'C',
        ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
&genFile($perMpPerMerc, $perMpPerMercHash{$perMpPerMerc});
```

You're passing a reference to an array.

So in

```
sub genFile {
    my ( $outFileName, @skuArr ) = @_;
```

You have to do :

```
sub genFile {
    my ( $outFileName, $skuArr ) = @_;
```

and then use `@$skuArr`.

Have a look at [references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

The modified genFile sub will be:

```
sub genFile {
    my ( $outFileName, $skuArr ) = @_;
    my $output = new IO::File(">$outFileName");
    my $writer = new XML::Writer( OUTPUT => $output, DATA_MODE => 1, DATA_INDENT => 2);
 #mpId is generated.
    &prepareMessage($writer, $mpId, @$skuArr);
}
```

And the other sub don't need to be modified.

Or you can pass always `skuArr`  by reference:

```
&genFile($perMpPerMerc, $perMpPerMercHash{$perMpPerMerc});
...
sub genFile {
    my ( $outFileName, $skuArr ) = @_;
    ...
    &prepareMessage($writer, $mpId, $skuArr);
}

sub prepareMessage {
    my ( $writer,  $mpId, $skuArr ) = @_;
    my $count = 1;
    print Dumper $skuArr; 
    foreach my $sku ( @$skuArr ) {
        print "loop run" , $sku, "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: @Could you elaborate more on what such construct do or pointers to read from. Also how to read this value in `prepareMessage`

Comment: I wrote the following in `prepareMessage`: `my ( $writer,  $mpId, $skuArr ) = @_;` This is not working.